# Webpack babel-loader for Bootstrap 4 JS Components (Windows vs Linux)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack, babel-loader

I'm trying to load individual components into my project from Bootstrap 4 using babel-loader and Webpack 3. My webpack-config file has this:

```html
// Support for Individual Bootstrap Component Loading
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: [__dirname + '/assets/js/', __dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/js/'],
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['env', 'stage-2'],
                        plugins: ['transform-runtime']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

...and i'm importing like so:

```html
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
// Components ========================================================= *
// Util Dependency (req'd)
import 'bootstrap/js/src/util';
// Modal
import 'bootstrap/js/src/modal';
```

The above is working in a Linux environment (on my Mac, it launches the modal) - it compiles the JS from my node_modules bootstrap dependency.

On a Windows machine, same code gets me this error:

```html
internal/streams/legacy.js:59
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^
Error: ./node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/modal.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (223:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     _getConfig(config) {
|       config = {
|         ...Default,
|         ...config
|       }
```

I understood this was a lack of support for the Spread Operator, so I added the `babel-preset-stage-2` dependency, but still didn't seem to resolve it on the Windows side.

So close (I think??) any help/ideas as to how to get this working would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you solve that already? I'm having the same problem right now.